# Redux Action not being fired

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have setup an application with Relay, Redux and GraphQL. When I fire an action to show the dropdown the state is not updated (The state is updated when I use react-redux devtools to dispatch the action.)
I have the following action:

```
export function showDropdown() { 
  return {  
    type: SHOW_DROPDOWN,
    dropdownType: PROFILE_SETTINGS,
    dropdownProps: {}
  }                                                                                                              
 }
```

and the following component

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { showDropdown } from '../../redux/actions/dropdownActions';

function StreamWidget() {
  const onClickHandler = () => {
  this.props.showDropdown();
}

return (
  <div>
    <a
      href='#'
      role='button'
      onClick={ onClickHandler }
    />
  </div>
);
}
export default connect(null, { showDropdown })(StreamWidget);
```

When I click the link I get
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'showDropdown' of undefined`

and when I change `this.props.showDropdown()` to `showDropdown()` I do not get the error but nothing happens the store is not updated.

I welcome all suggestions on how I can solve this. Thankyou

```
// Router
const Router = createFarceRouter({
  historyProtocol: new BrowserProtocol(),
  historyMiddlewares: [queryMiddleware],
  routeConfig: routes,

  render: createRender({}),
});

// Redux
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  compose (
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && 
window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
 )
);

// Render component into DOM element.
const render = Component => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router resolver={new Resolver(environment)} />
      </Provider>
    </AppContainer>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is not a props of your component so you should call it directly without this.props (showDropDown())

Besides, you have the error about the "marked as required" as you must have defined your React properties as required in your propTypes so you should remove the related line.

And in order to fire an action you should dispatch it and to do so you need to get access to that function. This can be done through the mapDispatchToProps function and connect.

Comment: When I do this in the component
.
` const onClickHandler = () => props.openTheDropdown()`
and define 
   
`const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
      openTheDropdown: () => { 
        dispatch({
          type: 'SHOW_DROPDOWN',
          dropdownType: 'PROFILE_SETTINGS',
          dropdownProps: {}
        }) 
      }
    });


export default connect(
  null, 
  mapDispatchToProps
)(StreamWidget)`

I still can not see the action being fired. I think for some reason connect is not properly sending down the value of showDropdown..

Comment: In your component don't forget to call you method via this.props and not just props.

Comment: Do you see that the function is called when clicking on the button ?

Answer (score 2):

The props are passed as an argument to your function:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { showDropdown } from '../../redux/actions/dropdownActions';

function StreamWidget(props) {
  const onClickHandler = () => props.showDropdown()

  return (
   <div>
    <a
      href='#'
      role='button'
      onClick={ onClickHandler }
    />
  </div>
  );
}
export default connect(null, { showDropdown })(StreamWidget);
```

Comment: Thank you, but even after those changes it still doesn't update state. I have edited the question to include index.js. Since I am also getting an error that says `Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `children` is marked as required in `App`, but its value is `undefined`. in App`. Perhaps theres something wrong with the store.

Comment: @MaryCahill Did you define any `propTypes`?

Comment: In main `<App />` component I have children as a required node. And in the component in question I have `showDropdown` as required function. The latter does not complain - Which i believe means that the function is defined..